# Column in SQL being deleted on UPDATE

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I have a table of values that uses a Where clause to find the row and then updates the values in the row. However it is deleting the value it is searching for after it is already found. So it finds the row using the stockid (not a PK) and updates the row, but leaves the stockid blank afterwards

```
$data = array( 
    'towSet'             => $towSet,
    'transWare'          => $transWare,
    'oceanFreightBooked' => $oceanFreightBooked,
    'BOLrec'             => $BOLrec,
    'BOLsent'            => $BOLsent,
);

$this->db
    ->where('stockid', $stockHold)
    ->update('logistics_tracking', $data);
```

The Strange part is that using this code doing the same thing it works perfectly fine

```
$data = array( 
    'recTitle'      => $recTitle,
    'recPOA'        => $recPOA,
    'recTitleState' => $recTitleState,
    'titleSent'     => $titleSent,
);

$this->db
    ->where('stockid', $stockHold)
    ->update('title_tracking', $data);
```

So as a reminder all the other values (towSet, transWare, oceanFreightBooked, ect.. ) all insert and it just blanks out the stockid after updating

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You say: "*all **insert** and it just blanks out the stockid after **updating***"

So, is it `INSERT` or `UPDATE`?  The behavior you're describing is consistent with `INSERT`.

Comment: You are reading the code.... it is an Update..

Comment: Your code looks fine, it should not be updating the `stockid` field with null values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah the code was fine, apparently I was just doing too much with one function. Created an external function and passed through an array of the data. Weird.

Thanks for looking!